# Why we can't take torque equation for the mid point of the ladder in the question **Source IIT JEE 2005 PHYSICS**

Tags: homework-and-exercises, rotational-dynamics

**Question** (Source IIT JEE 2005 Physics)

Two identical ladders, each of mass M and length L are resting on the rough horizontal surface as shown in the figure. A block of mass m hangs from P. If the system is in equilibrium, find the magnitude and the direction of frictional force at A and B.

*Attempt*

For the equilibrium of the whole system:

$ΣFy=0$
So,$$N=\frac{(2M+m)g}{2}$$

And for rotational equilibrium

$$mg\frac{lcos(\theta)}{2} +N(\frac{lcos(\theta)}{2}-f\frac{lsin\theta}{2}=0$$ This what I have written for either rod's rotational equilibrium about the mid point of the rod since the rod is in equilibrium.

**Main Difficulty**

When I approached my teacher for the answer, mine was wrong and then my teacher tried to explain why it should not be correct for the rotational equilibrium equation for the rod, I was not able to understand. This step is my main difficulty or obstacle. Please help me in clearing this doubt.

[image]

Thank you for helping me.

Comment: N at point P is missing.

Comment: @npojo "N at point P is missing"...so...? Sorry but it will be helpful if you can elaborate on it further... Thanks again!

Comment: The left ladder presses the right ladder at point P. This is a force you need to include as a torque unless you select P as your axis of rotation.

Comment: So, finally understood my mistake. Thanks again! And @npojo your explanation was simple but compelling. If you can make your last comment as answer I can surely upvote it for answer.

Comment: Did that, but what do you mean by compelling?

Comment: I mean to say in a nice way - convincingly true. Sorry for wrong choice of word.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/85892/discussion-between-jayant98-and-npojo).

Comment: Why downvote? I showed where the specific problem is; showed my attempt to make it clear for others about my understanding about that part...What else do you need in this problem?

Comment: Might be useful to include what the teacher said, otherwise we'll probably just repeat that...

Comment: What @PhysicsDave answered it was roughly the same explanation but without any exercise:just the fact that there will be a force which he said that I have not accounted in my equation. And the problem was that he wasn't able to explain what force is present (though it is simple) but neither he was able to explain nor I was able to get it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The left ladder presses the right ladder at point P. This is a force you need to include as a torque unless you select P as your axis of rotation.

Answer (score 0):

Consider a ladder leaning against a smooth wall at 45 degrees (no friction), assume force on ladder is 100N due to gravity at the centre of mass, length 4m. Use the some of torques at the bottom (floor has friction) and you should get 35N is a force at the top perpendicular to the later, resolve this force at 45 degrees to the wall (0.707 factor), you should get a force in x dir of 24.7N.   I know this may not answer your question directly but should give an insight.